# Having trouble to get the files from android emulator (Titanium)

Tags: android, android-emulator, filesystems, titanium

guys! I have trouble to get files from my android emulator!

① Here is my emulator info:
**Genymotion for personal use - Samsung Galaxy Note 3 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920**

② And here is the file's tree of the emulator:
[image]

I had stored two mp3 files for test in the ***Internal storage*** directory, and the path is ***/storage/emulated/0/Download***.
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the two mp3 files are in the ***Download*** directory. My trouble is that I can never get the two files right path.

③ Here is my code:

```
if(Ti.Filesystem.isExternalStoragePresent()){
    var sdkDir_1 = Ti.Filesystem.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    console.info('------------->sdkDir_1');
    console.info(sdkDir_1);

    var sdkDir_2 = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory);
    console.info('------------->sdkDir_2');
    console.info(sdkDir_2);

    var downLoadDir = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(sdkDir_2.parent.directoryListing[7]);
    console.info('------------->downLoadDir.getDirectoryListing()');
    console.info(downLoadDir.getDirectoryListing());
    ...
```

and here is the console:

```
[INFO] [android, 4.4.4, 10.0.3.15] ------------->sdkDir_1
[INFO] [android, 4.4.4, 10.0.3.15] appdata://

[INFO] [android, 4.4.4, 10.0.3.15] ------------->sdkDir_2
[INFO] [android, 4.4.4, 10.0.3.15] {
"readonly": false,
"bubbleParent": true,
"writable": true,
"directoryListing": [],
"symbolicLink": false,
"apiName": "Ti.Filesystem.File",
"hidden": false,
"nativePath": "file:///storage/emulated/0/co.test.zone",
"executable": false,
"size": 4096,
"name": "co.happysoft.zone",
"parent": {
    "readonly": false,
    "bubbleParent": true,
    "writable": true,
    "directoryListing": [
        "Music",
        "Podcasts",
        "Ringtones",
        "Alarms",
        "Notifications",
        "Pictures",
        "Movies",
        "Download",
        "DCIM",
        "Android",
        "storage",
        ...

 [INFO] [android, 4.4.4, 10.0.3.15] ------------->downLoadDir
 [INFO] [android, 4.4.4, 10.0.3.15] {
        "readonly": true,
        "bubbleParent": true,
        "writable": false,
        "directoryListing": [],
        "symbolicLink": false,
        "apiName": "Ti.Filesystem.File",
        "hidden": false,
        "nativePath": "file:///android_asset/Resources/api/Download",
        "executable": false,
        "size": 0,
        "name": "/Download",
        "parent": null
  }
```

I'm so confused that how the ***Download*** path should changed and it's ***directoryListing*** has nothing. And, I'm wonder why the ***sdkDir_1*** has nothing too. Anyone have a good solution to me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks **@Fokke Zandbergen** so much that remind me I had made a mistake that try to get the emulator's internal files through the **external storage directory**. And now, it's clear that if you want to get the local files from the **emulator** or real **mobile device**, maybe the follow suggestions may help you:

**① Get local files from emulator**

[1](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Filesystem_Access_and_Storage) **Android**, try this path: **file:///storage/emulated/0**

First, the directory **emulated** is only special for the emulator, all the android emulator have this directory. And then, the directory **0** is means your emulator only have one internal storage directory, cause there're no external storage **sdcard** for the emulator.

[2] **iPhone**, try this path: **/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F34851D0-AFA5-443E-AEF6-70B695FB9C5E/data**

For the directory **F34851D0-AFA5-443E-AEF6-70B695FB9C5E**, it's the simulator ID which you can check it by ***ti info*** command.

**② Get local files from real mobile device**

[1](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Filesystem_Access_and_Storage) **Android**, try this path: **file:///storage/sdcard0**

Note this, **sdcard0** is the internal storage of your mobile device. If you need to get the local files from external storage directory, also means **SD card** then you should try this way:

```
if(Ti.Filesystem.isExternalStoragePresent()){
    var sdkDir = Ti.Filesystem.getExternalStorageDirectory();
}
```

[2] **iPhone**, cause iPhone have not the external storage, so its same to the simulator. Well, I have not test this way, maybe you should have a try.

---

---

Well guys, I had tested the real mobile device file path recently, which I mean the file path of ***SDCard(external storage)***. However,there's a bad news I should tell you, the method that [Titanium API](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Filesystem_Access_and_Storage) afford to detect the if the external storage exists is not good to use. Here is the details:

1. ***if(Ti.Filesystem.isExternalStoragePresent())*** always return true although, the **SDCard** don't present.

   I supposed that, nowadays, almost all of the smartphones were built embed with a ***internal storage*** (never means the smartphone's selves storage like *phonebook*, I mean the *internal storage* is a special external storage but embed into the smartphone), the SDCard is a extend storage, but they're same.
2. ***different manufacturer has different settings of the external storage***

   During my test, when the smartphone comes from **HUAWEI** the external storage path become: ***file:///storage/sdcard1***, distinguished with internal storage ***sdcard0***.

   However, when the manufacturer is **SAMSUNG**, the external storage path is: ***file:///storage/extSdCard***.

   So, we have to check the manufacture to define the external storage path:

   ```
   var sdCardPath;
   if(Ti.Platform.manufacturer == 'HUAWEI'){
       sdCardPath = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('file:///storage/sdcard1');
   }
   else if(Ti.Platform.manufacturer == 'samsung'){
       sdCardPath = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('file:///storage/extSdCard');
   }
   ```

   Well, it's so terrible!

So, I have been not get a good idea to approach the file from the real mobile devices by different manufacture. Guys, do you have a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Internal Storage is private to the app that stored them:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Please use external storage for files that you need to access from apps other then those who created them.

Comment: Thanks **Fokke Zandbergen** so much. I had worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

open the emulated folder files list, select all files or just the files needed then choose move files from three dots and confirm then files reach the 'Download' folder which is easily accessible from gallery or storage file tree