# Parsing the .mp3 file to get the song's information in Titanium

Tags: node.js, titanium, media

guys! Recently, I'm struggled to parse the **.mp3** file (or other types) to get the song's information (like: **album title**, **album cover**, **song's name**, **singer**, **duration and size** of the song etc.) in **Titanium**! Cause I can't find a good method in **API** to solve the problem (I had try **Titanium Media**, but never help), so I had try this node module **[musicmetadata](https://github.com/leetreveil/musicmetadata)**. However there're some problems to apply the node-module in Titanium, although, **[here](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154529/how-to-use-nodejs-modules-with-titanium)** is a good suggestion but can't help me.

Here is the file tree after installed the **musicmetadata**:

[image]

According to the musicmetadata API, I have to state the follow code in my js file (***Resources/ui/index.js***):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mm = require('musicmetadata');
```

However, as far as I know, the **require** method in Titanium just cover the range under the **Resources** directory. Here is my js files directory:

[image]

So, there're comes the error that can't find the module. Maybe there're have a bad way that just copy the module under the ***Resources/lib*** path may help, however it's not smart. The real problem is the **fs** module (this is which I can't understand, I supposed it's maybe point the **filereader-stream** node module that was included in the musicmetadata). How can I require the musicmetadata module properly in my js file? Or, Is there a good method to parse the mp3 file in Titanium API ? Guys, I need your help! Thanks in advance, and I'll so appreciate your suggestions or ideas!

Comment: Don't think trying to import node.js modules is the way to go here...while it might work with some really simple modules that have no dependencies on core node modules or other libraries, i don't think that will work for the vast majority of cases and certainly not for "fs".

Comment: Thanks @Cviejo anyway! I'm not intend to apply the node module into my project really, cause as you commented it's really a big problem to fix these **dependencies** or **libraries** of the node module, just like the **"fs"** which I have no choice to make it work. Now, I'm trying to find a good way to parse the mp3 file in native javascript method or, if I'm lucky enough, there're would be a shortcut which someone can told me in **Titanium API**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use NPM packages in Titanium apps. Only `Resources` will be packaged with your app and even if you would place the `node_modules` folder in there, Titanium's `require()` won't resolve it properly. And then there's the problem that the JavaScriptCore engine Titanium uses does not support the NodeJS APIs like `fs`. What you should do is use https://github.com/smclab/titaniumifier to convert `musicmetadata` in a single CommonJS file that you can require in Titanium. It shims `fs` and some other core NodeJS APIs and concats all `musicmetadata` JS files and its dependencies into one file.

Comment: Well, thanks **@Fokke Zandbergen** ! I'm so appreciate you had afford the [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446806/having-trouble-to-get-the-files-from-android-emulator-titanium) to me in my last question that about get the local files from the emulator, and fortunately, I had worked it out. Have you ever checked it? And I'm also thanks for you give me the suggestion here. Yes, you're quite right, it's really a big trouble to apply the node-module into Titanium app project, and **@Cviejo** had remind me already. And now, I had give up this way. Thanks anyway!