# titanium studio save image into the native gallery

Tags: image, gallery, native, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i would know if it's possible to save an image (from imageView, retrieve by webservice not from the camera) in the native gallery, both on ios and android ?

I suppose that yes, but i can't find the native gallery path to use for saving file (like Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. If you want to save the image into device's gallery you might use saveToPhotoGallery method:
https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media-method-saveToPhotoGallery

If you want to save the file inside the device, have a look at this code snippet:
https://gist.github.com/timoa/3733505

Comment: In my case the image is retrieve by a webservice, not directly from the camera, so i can't use saveToGallery property. So i just need the final path of native gallery so save my file

Comment: @gsoulie why can't you use `saveToPhotoGallery()` with an image retrieved by a webservice? You'll have the image as a Blob or File, which both are valid arguments for the method.

Comment: You right, I was thinking that this method was only a camera option type. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

@gsoulie Just have a look at my problem that I met before, [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446806/having-trouble-to-get-the-files-from-android-emulator-titanium)! Hope this can help you!